# Use of slicing numpy object in a list

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a problem using the numpy slicing. I don't even know how to give this problem a name or title.

Below are a segment of test code.

```
import numpy
input_items = []
output_items = []
input_items.insert(0,  numpy.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=numpy.float32))
output_items.insert(0,  numpy.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=numpy.float32))
in0 = input_items[0]
out = output_items[0]

print "Before, input_items[0] : {0}".format(input_items[0])
print "Before, output_items[0]: {0}".format(output_items[0])
out[:] = in0 * 2 
#out = in0 * 2
print "After, input_item[0]  : {0}".format(input_items[0])
print "After, output_item[0] : {0}".format(output_items[0])
```

If I use `out[:] = in0 * 2`, I will get:

```
Before, input_items[0] : [ 1.  2.  3.]
Before, output_items[0]: [ 0.  0.  0.]
After, input_items[0]  : [ 1.  2.  3.]
After, output_items[0] : [ 2.  4.  6.]
```

If I use `out = in0 * 2`, I will get:

```
Before, input_items[0] : [ 1.  2.  3.]
Before, output_items[0]: [ 0.  0.  0.]
After, input_items[0]  : [ 1.  2.  3.]
After, output_items[0] : [ 0.  0.  0.]
```

In the code, I have assign `output_items[0]` to `out`, but obviously the use of `out` or `out[:]` can affect the result of `output_items[0]`. Could anyone figure it out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

`out[:] = in0 * 2` changes your original array, because in numpy **slicing is a *view* on the original array (which is NOT a copy)**, so you get a reference to it and change it

`out = in0 * 2` doesn't change any original array, because you are simply assigning a computed result to `out` (the result is stored in a fresh new separate array), therefore isn't a reference to `output_items` or `input_items`

If you need to copy an array, you can use `numpy.copy()`, not just assign `out = output_items[0]`
If you assign without a copy, you are still modifying the same array, so that change will reflect elsewhere (e.g. between `out` and `output_items[0]`

So e.g. if you do `out = output_items[0].copy()`, now out has a fresh new array copied from the values in `output_items[0]`, but won't be affecting it

ref http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: Thanks @bakkal. If assigning `out = output_items[0]` without a copy, I am still modifying the same array, then I get confused about why `out = in0 * 2` does not affect `output_items[0]`.

Comment: Why would `out = in0 * 2` change `output_items`, they are unrelated in anyway. You could ask why ins't `out = in0 * 2` capable of changing `in0`, and that's because `in0 * 2` gives you a new array with the computed values in it, changing that resulting array won't change `in0`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear for my question. Can I said that if I do out[:] = in0 * 2, I am not accessing a variable called out, instead I am changing output_items[0] (because out[:] is a reference pointing to output_items[0]). On the other hand, if I do out = in0 * 2, I am access a variable called out. Am I understanding it correctly?